# AWS Alarm - Lambda Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an Alarm that monitors `Metric Name: Errors` and is triggered when any AWS Lambda function encounters an error.

Unfortunately, the alarm does not specify which Lambda / Log Stream caused the error.

Is there a way to include that information in the alarm notification?

Comment: How is that metric populated? Every AWS Lambda function creates function-specific metrics that includes a count of errors. You could look at those function-specific metrics to identify which function is generating errors.

Comment: Thank you John. The metric is the standard Errors count offered by CloudWatch. After some digging I found that CloudWatch Charting exposes the function names. Thanks again for your comment.